# Generate transient property in entity before it gets serialized

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have a user entity that has a transient fullname property. This fullname property should be generated by calling a method on my Util service by passing in the lastname and firstname properties of the user entity(which are not transient but are write only). How can i do this before the entity gets serialized and returned in my response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that in your model. I create simple Person model and do this.

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Transient;

@Entity
@Table(name = "PERSON")
public class Person implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "FIRSTNAME")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "LASTNAME")
    private String lastName;

    @Transient
    private String fullName;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getFullName() {
        fullName = firstName + " " + lastName;
        return fullName;
    }

    public void setFullName(String fullName) {
        this.fullName = fullName;
    }

}
```